# mousemove target element returns not required or correct element

Tags: javascript, jquery, svg

I have a set of svg element

```
<svg id="container_svg" style="width: 700px; height: 600px;>
<rect width='600' height='600'> </rect>
<g>
<path d="M  285 0 L 285 0 L 318.34499999999997 57.5055 L 251.655 57.5055 z"/>
</g>
</svg>
```

and added a mousemove event to svg element in document.ready as

```
$("#container_svg").mousemove(function(evt){
  var child=$(evt.target)[0].nodeName;
 });
```

So moving on svg element, the event get triggered but getting different target element in different browser as below.
Even though moving on the path element in svg, i am getting $(evt.target)[0].nodeName as "rect" in firefox,
but in IE and chrome $(evt.target)[0].nodeName returns "path" as i want...

Thanks,

Siva

Comment: When I tried this it seemed to work. Perhaps you should create a jsfiddle that shows the problem.

Answer (score -1):

Cross browsers solution:

```
  $("#container_svg *").mousemove(function(evt){
     //var child=$(evt.target)[0].nodeName;
     evt.stopPropagation();
     var child=$(evt.currentTarget)[0].nodeName;
   });
```

don't know why you down-voted my previews answer...